# Animation Listener not working in FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a animation custom drawer menu class calling from 5 different activity , in 4 of them it works fine, but in one of them that i'm using `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity` not working.

the behavior of menu in FragmentActivity is weird , in debug mode the code running well but it seems the drawer menu class have not `UIthread`, even when i'm using runOnUiThread.

I'm initialize the custom drawer class on `onCreate()` method of each `Activity` and in button click just call the `DraverVisibility()` method in Drawer class.

MainActivity class :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
 DraverMenu DraverMenu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DraverMenu = new DraverMenu(this,
                findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                findViewById(R.id.draver_l1),
                findViewById(R.id.activity_main_app_name),
                findViewById(R.id.activity_main_app_icon),
                findViewById(R.id.draver_change_language));

...

@Override
public boolean onCreatePanelMenu(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    DraverMenu.DraverVisibility();
    return false;
}
```

class DraverMenu :

```
public class DraverMenu {
    private final Activity A;
    private final int LEFT_DRAVER_MARGIN = 220;
    private final int TOP_DRAVER_MARGIN = 45;
    private final int OPEN_DRAVER_DURATION = 300;
    private final int CLOSE_DRAVER_DURATION = 200;
    private float left_px;
    private float top_px;
    private LinearLayout draver;
    private View content;


public DraverMenu(Activity a, View content, View draver,
                  final View name, View icon, View language) {
    this.A = a;
    this.draver = (LinearLayout) draver;
    left_px = ...;
    top_px = ...;
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams parm = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) draver.getLayoutParams();
    // if api<
    parm.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    parm.leftMargin = -(int) left_px;
    parm.topMargin = (int) top_px;
    draver.setLayoutParams(parm);
    this.content = content;
...
}


public void DraverVisibility() {
    int vis = draver.getVisibility();
    if (vis == View.VISIBLE) {
        TranslateAnimation movetoleft = new TranslateAnimation(0, -left_px, 0, 0);
        movetoleft.setDuration(CLOSE_DRAVER_DURATION);

        movetoleft.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams parm = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)
                        draver.getLayoutParams();
                // if api<
                parm.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
                parm.leftMargin = -(int) left_px;
                parm.topMargin = (int) top_px;
                draver.setLayoutParams(parm);
                draver.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                draver.setAnimation(null);
                draver.invalidate();
                content.setAnimation(null);
                content.invalidate();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        });
        draver.startAnimation(movetoleft);
    }
    if (vis == View.INVISIBLE) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) A.getSystemService(
                Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(draver.getWindowToken(), 0);

        TranslateAnimation movetoRight = new TranslateAnimation(0, left_px, 0, 0);
        movetoRight.setDuration(OPEN_DRAVER_DURATION);
        movetoRight.setFillEnabled(true);

        movetoRight.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                draver.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams parm = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) draver.getLayoutParams();
                // if api<
                parm.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
                parm.leftMargin = 0;  //-(int)left_px;
                parm.topMargin = (int) top_px;
                draver.setLayoutParams(parm);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        });
        draver.startAnimation(movetoRight);
    }
 }
}
```

The XML of DrawerMenu is inclode in MainActivity XML
DrawerMenu XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#cc000000"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@id/draver_l1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView" android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/draver_language_button_text"
            android:id="@id/draver_change_language"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/draver_software_info"
            android:id="@id/draver_button_2"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/draver_contact_us"
            android:id="@id/draver_button_3"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView1" android:background="@drawable/barcodeqr"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

any suggestion ?

Comment: what do you mean by "it seems the drawer menu class have not UIthread, even when i'm using runOnUiThread."

Comment: Sorry I wrote wrong instead of `FragmentActivity`, ListActivity. Because after click to show animation noting happened but if swipe viewpager to another Fragment , for 1 second animation come a gone.

Comment: where do you call DraverVisibility in your project? post onCreate method of your main activity, also your main xml file.

Comment: i post Activity and xml

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort